# Formatting a dynamic table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-events

I have the following dynamic table:

```
dtable = "<table style='background-color:purple;'><tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'> Start </td>";
dtable += "<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'> Name </td></tr>";
dtable += "<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>" + Data["start"] + "</td>";
dtable += "<td style='width: 100px;  text-align: right;'>" + Data["name"] + "</td></tr>";
                                
dtable += "<tr><td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'></td>";
dtable += "<td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'></td></tr>";

dtable += "<tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'> Status </td>";
dtable += "<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'> ID </td></tr>";
dtable += "<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>" + Data["status"] + "</td>";
dtable += "<td style='width: 100px;  text-align: right;'>" + Data["ID"] + "</td></tr>";
                                
dtable += "<tr><td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'></td>";
dtable += "<td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'></td></tr>";

dtable += "<tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'> Title</td>";
```

The display would be in two columns where the first column contains **Start** and **Name** as columns
and the second column contains **Status** and **ID**.

I want to put a border against the first column and a border against the second column as well.

I cannot use any other functions like jQuery to calculate and put the borders against left and right columns because this is just a dynamic content.

Is there any alteration for the above table to group and put border against them?
I am basically clicking a button and on the click building this table and showing.
edited :  dtable typo

Comment: is the `dcontent` in there a typo?

Comment: dcontent is just "var"

Comment: I have no idea what that means - but its weird you're concatenating a big long string in to `dtable` and half way through you put one single cell into `dcontent`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo , dcontent was a typo

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  Alternating both border colors and background colors.

```
<html>
    <script>
            function init(){
            var Data= {name:'bin', ID:7, status:'good', start:'today'}
            dtable = "<table class='TFtableCol' style='background-color:purple;'><tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'> Start </td>";
    dtable += "<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'> Name </td></tr>";
    dtable += "<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>" + Data["start"] + "</td>";
    dtable += "<td style='width: 100px;  text-align: right;'>" + Data["name"] + "</td></tr>";

    dtable += "<tr><td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'></td>";
    dtable += "<td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'></td></tr>";

    dtable += "<tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'> Status </td>";
    dtable += "<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'> ID </td></tr>";
    dtable += "<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>" + Data["status"] + "</td>";
    dtable += "<td style='width: 100px;  text-align: right;'>" + Data["ID"] + "</td></tr>";

    dtable += "<tr><td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'></td>";
    dtable += "<td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'></td></tr>";
    dtable +="</table>"
    //dtable += "<tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'> Title</td>";   
    document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = dtable;
    } 
            </script>
    <body onload='init()'>


    <style type="text/css">
        .TFtableCol{
            width:100%; 
            border-collapse:collapse; 
        }
        .TFtableCol td{ 
            padding:7px; border:2px solid;
        }
        /* improve visual readability for IE8 and below */
        .TFtableCol tr{
            background: #b8d1f3;
        }
        /*  Define the background color for all the ODD table columns  */
        .TFtableCol tr td:nth-child(odd){ 
            background: #b8d1f3;
            border-color:Red;
        }
        /*  Define the background color for all the EVEN table columns  */
        .TFtableCol tr td:nth-child(even){
            background: #dae5f4;
            border-color:green;
        }
    </style>


    <form>
        <div id='d' style='width:600px'></div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```